# How do I know the compression algorithm used by Compact Os in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, filesystems, compression

By using the command `compact.exe /compactos:query` all I get is if compact OS compression is activated or not, but not what compression algorithm is used, such as LZX, XPRESS4K, XPRESS8K or XPRESS16K.

I tried `compact.exe /exe:algorithm` as suggested at https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/dirs/Windows/System32/compact_exe with no luck. it does not understand the switch and returns general explanations for the list of switches like `/?` does.

FYI I compressed the drive after windows installation using `compact.exe /compactos:always` command without any additional switches.  Performance so far so good.

Another question is, I read in several articles that only system files or executable files are compressed via this method. Can I rest assured that data files like pdf, images, audios, txt, etc. do not be compressed?

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com//help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: are you the same person as [this one](https://superuser.com/q/1719973/241386)? If yes please [merge the accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts). StackExchange doesn't allow one to have multiple accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I know the compression algorithm used by `CompactOs`

There doesn't seem to be a way of retrieving the algorithm used.

> I tried "compact.exe /exe:algorithm"

`algorithm` is a place holder. You should replace it with one of the supported compression methods:

> `/EXE` Use compression optimised for executable files which are read
> frequently and not modified,
>
> Supported algorithms are:
>
> `XPRESS4K` (fastest) default
>
> `XPRESS8K`
>
> `XPRESS16K`
>
> `LZX`   (most compact)

Source: [Compact - Compress files - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/compact.html)

Example usage:

```
compact /exe:XPRESS4K
```

> I compressed the drive after windows installation using `compact.exe /compactos:always` command without any additional switches.
> I read in several articles that only system files or executable files are compressed via this method

That is almost correct. It will only compress "OS binaries". This will probably include System executable and DLL files but won't include other non-system executable files.

> `/CompactOs`  Set or query the systems compression state.
>
> Supported options are:
>
> `query`  - Query the systems compact state.
>
> `always` - **Compress all OS binaries** and set the system state to non-compact.
>
> `never`  - Uncompress all OS binaries and set the system state to compact which remains unless an administrator changes it.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source: [Compact - Compress files - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/compact.html)

> . Can I rest assured that data files like pdf, images, audios, txt, etc. are not compressed?

Yes. The documentation doesn't mention these kinds of file.

Comment: Now I understand why that command didn't work. so there's no way to find out method post-compression. It's weird Microsoft does not give an option to achieve it which seems to be not too complicated! anyway thank you for the clarification, I will probably have to decompress first and recompress with specified algorithms. The problem for compact os is it won't compress new files , so "set and forget" convenience is not available..

Comment: @ungoogler there's a way to find out the compression algorithm, and compactOS is not meant for user data files and doesn't support writing on-the-fly so you can't have some thing like "set and forget"

Answer (score 6):

Compact.exe already shows you the algorithm by default

```
PS D:\compressed> compact *.txt

 Listing D:\compressed\
 New files added to this directory will not be compressed.

   195634 :     86016 = 2,3 to 1 C LZNT1.txt
   195634 :     45056 = 4,3 to 1 l LZX.txt
   195634 :    195634 = 1,0 to 1   No_compression.txt
   195634 :     69632 = 2,8 to 1 X XPRESS16K.txt
   195634 :     81920 = 2,4 to 1 x XPRESS4K.txt
   195634 :     73728 = 2,7 to 1 X XPRESS8K.txt
                                 ↑ compression algorithm
Of 6 files within 1 directories
5 are compressed and 1 are not compressed.
1.173.804 total bytes of data are stored in 551.986 bytes.
The compression ratio is 2,1 to 1.
```

See the second-to-last column, `C` means the default LZNT1 algorithm, `l` is LZX, `x` is XPRESS4K and `X` is XPRESS8K or XPRESS16K. In fact `compact` list files just like `dir` and you can use `compact /a` to show system/hidden files or `compact /s` to show files recursively

Unfortunately there isn't a way to differentiate XPRESS8K and XPRESS16K with `compact.exe` though, but you can do that by calling the Win32 API directly. The new algorithms for CompactOs are handled via Windows Overlay Filter (WOF) and you can use its [`WofIsExternalFile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wofapi/nf-wofapi-wofisexternalfile) API to retrieve compression info. I've written a PowerShell script named `compression.ps1` do do that. Here's its output for the same files above

```
PS D:\compressed> .\compression.ps1 (ls *.txt)

FileName                              Algorithm
--------                              ---------
D:\compressed\LZNT1.txt                   LZNT1
D:\compressed\LZX.txt                       LZX
D:\compressed\No_compression.txt NO_COMPRESSION
D:\compressed\XPRESS16K.txt           XPRESS16K
D:\compressed\XPRESS4K.txt             XPRESS4K
D:\compressed\XPRESS8K.txt             XPRESS8K
```

Here's its source code, just save as *.ps1 and run as above

```powershell
param(
    [Parameter()]
    [string[]]$fileList
)

Add-Type -Name 'Wof' -Namespace 'Wofutil' -MemberDefinition @'
    public struct ExternalFileInfo
    {
        public uint algorithm;
        public uint flags;
    }

    [DllImport("Wofutil.dll")]public static extern int WofIsExternalFile(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Filepath,
        out int IsExternalFile,
        out uint Provider,
        out ExternalFileInfo Info,
        ref uint BufferLength
    );
'@

enum Algorithms {
    NO_COMPRESSION = -2
    LZNT1          = -1
    XPRESS4K       = 0
    LZX            = 1
    XPRESS8K       = 2
    XPRESS16K      = 3
}

class CompressionInfo {
    [string]$FileName
    [Algorithms]$Algorithm
}

foreach ($fileName in $fileList) {
    $f = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $fileName
    if (($f.Attributes -band [IO.FileAttributes]::Compressed) -ne 0) {
        [CompressionInfo]@{
            FileName = $f
            Algorithm = 'LZNT1'
        }
    } else {
        [int]$isExternalFile = 0
        [uint32]$provider = 0
        $fileInfo = New-Object Wofutil.Wof+ExternalFileInfo
        [uint32]$length = 8

        [void][Wofutil.Wof]::WofIsExternalFile($f, [ref]$isExternalFile,
            [ref]$provider, [ref]$fileInfo, [ref]$length)
        if ($isExternalFile -ne 0) {
            [CompressionInfo]@{
                FileName = $f
                Algorithm = $fileInfo.algorithm
            }
        } else {
            [CompressionInfo]@{
                FileName = $f
                Algorithm = 'NO_COMPRESSION'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that NTFS compression and CompactOS are completely different features. When MS introduced the new CompactOS feature they merged it into the `compact` command because of their relation to compression. But CompactOS is purely to compress **read-only system files** to save the OS footprint. You can clearly see that the option is called `/exe` because it's meant to compress executable files. That's why the new algorithms aren't designed for editing and writing to the files will decompress them

```
PS D:\compressed> echo x >.\LZX.txt # Write more data to file

PS D:\compressed> compact .\LZX.txt # Now the file is uncompressed

 Listing D:\compressed\
 New files added to this directory will not be compressed.

        8 :         8 = 1,0 to 1   LZX.txt

Of 1 files within 1 directories
0 are compressed and 1 are not compressed.
8 total bytes of data are stored in 8 bytes.
The compression ratio is 1,0 to 1.
```

OTOH the NTFS compression feature uses the old LZNT1 algorithm and is designed to work with any files. It supports **on-the-fly editing** where you can write to the files arbitrarily and they're still compressed. You can also mark new files in the folder to be compressed automatically with LZNT1 but [not with the new algorithms](https://superuser.com/q/979702/241386)

Note that the `/exe` option isn't for *checking* the algorithm but to **specify** an algorithm when compressing. `compact /C /exe:<algorithm> your_files` will compress the specified files with the specified EXE algorithm, whereas `compact /C your_files` will compress the files using NTFS compression

Comment: thank you for the detailed information about compact compression! so windows decides what to compress, but the problem here is sometimes windows automatically activate compression without even noticing, which is pretty something some users find unhelpful, or even harmful because low end old ssds have relatively higher corruption ratio , and actively compressing/decompressing files would greatly increase the possibility of files unintentionally altered..

Comment: @ungoogler the Windows installer actually does a benchmark to find out the best solution for each case, which is probably what the [`WofShouldCompressBinaries`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wofapi/nf-wofapi-wofshouldcompressbinaries) function returns. It never actively compresses/decompresses files. Once a file is compressed, it stays that way, and since those files are read-only, there should be no problem whatsoever. In fact reducing the IO also reduces the data written so it can reduce wear on the SSD. That said, I have an ~8-year old SSD and it still works until now

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your primary question - what algorithm does CompactOS use - I can confirm it [always uses `XPRESS4K`](https://sourceforge.net/p/wimlib/discussion/general/thread/ccaf79d9/). No need to check with the `compact` command.

In addition, CompactOS [does not allow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/22088-compress-uncompress-windows-10-compact-os-4.html#post1667375) user to choose the algorithm. If you try combining the `/CompactOS` and `/EXE` command-line arguments, `compact.exe` will not recognize them.